# Running script via crontab on reboot

Tags: scripts, cron

I am using Ubuntu Server 16.04. Everytime I log in, I need to manually run my script: `/home/user/ini.sh`. This script calls other scripts that need `sudo` permissions, so I get the prompt, insert my password and done. Now I want to configure a way to run the script automatically when the system starts.

I have used `crontab -e`and added the line

```
@reboot /home/user/ini.sh
```

This does not seem to work. I have tried different options as suggested by other users in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335615/does-ubuntu-support-reboot-in-crontab), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19634/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-of-windows-startup) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863240/cronjob-script-not-running-on-reboot).

```
@reboot user    /home/user/ini.sh
@reboot root    /home/user/ini.sh
@reboot sh      /home/user/ini.sh
*/1 * * * *     /home/user/ini.sh
....
```

adding `SHELL=/bin/bash`...
But I cannot get it to work. I have also tried

```
@reboot echo "yes" > /home/user/yes.txt
```

And the file is created - empty though, with no content inside (this demonstrates something is working but I am making a mistake somewhere).

Where is my error?

---

**EDIT**

I have also **unsuccessfully** tried to `sudo crontab -e` and use

```
@reboot root    /home/user/ini.sh
```

Comment: Are you using the user's cron or the roots one ?

Comment: Because if you have to run it as root, you need to edit crontab for the root user (sudo crontab -e)

Comment: Jobs inserted via `crontab -e` (whether your user or the root user i.e. `sudo crontab -e`) should NOT include the user field after the time spec - that's only for system jobs (i.e. `/etc/crontab`)

Comment: I am using it as "user", which is how ideally the script should run. But in any case, it is strange the case with the echo, I am doing something wrong somwhere - unless cron @reboot only works woth root

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver, although this is not the error, because I have used it with no user field too

Comment: *"This script calls other scripts that need sudo permissions"* - this means you have to either run this as elevated user (root) or configure passwordless sudo.

Comment: See also this [excellent answer on why this is a bad idea](https://askubuntu.com/a/173930/783023)

Comment: You should write a proper init scritpt

Comment: @RobertRiedl So what is the solution? I don't want to run as root, but the script needs to call other scripts as other users. And even the simple "echo" is not working. Also, I think both your links point to the same place.

Answer (score 4):

There is a big difference between *reboot* and *login*, and your system treats them both quite differently.

- REBOOT jobs are run by the root user (not your user), and must be headless (no display). The best way to do boot-time jobs in 16.04 and newer is to create a [service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159462/what-is-systemds-target-service-and-socket), and include that service in the appropriate systemd [target](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159462/what-is-systemds-target-service-and-socket) during the boot process.
- LOGIN jobs are run by your user (not root) after you enter your password. The best way to do login jobs is to place them in your `~/.config/autostart/` directory.

But you have a second problem. You seem to want a user-level job to use root-level services. There are many, many ways to do this.

- The *easiest* way is to simply run your script as root manually every day. You already know how to do this, so let's look at other options.
- The *fastest* way is to hack at the `sudoers` file and generate a special permission set. However, it may not backup properly with the rest of your system, AppArmor may block some actions anyway, and it's hard to troubleshoot and maintain.
- The *appropriate* way is to separate your user-level and root-level functions into two separate scripts, and to use dbus to launch the root-level script and return it's output. This is easy to maintain and troubleshoot, but requires the greatest skill and a bit of learning about dbus.

Comment: That was insightful. I found another option for LOGIN jobs, which is the use of `.profile` (it needs the user to log in). I will do some testing and post the result